# Find the isomorphic ring with $\mathbb{Z_6}[x] / \langle x^3-x \rangle$ (Chinese remainder thm)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$\mathbb{Z_6}[x] / \langle x^3-x \rangle$  (*C.R.T. means chinese remainder theorem)

I've got the two solutions. Let me introduce them.

**First solution.** Considering the $\langle x \rangle$, $\langle x-1 \rangle$ and $\langle x+1 \rangle$ are pairwise coprime, by C.R.T.

$\mathbb{Z_6}[x] / \langle x^3-x \rangle$ $\simeq$  $\mathbb{Z_6}[x] / \langle x \rangle$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z_6}[x] / \langle x-1 \rangle$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z_6}[x] / \langle x+1 \rangle$ $\simeq$ $\mathbb{Z_6} \times \mathbb{Z_6} \times \mathbb{Z_6}  $

**Second solution.** $\mathbb{Z_6}[x] / \langle x^3-x \rangle$ $\simeq$  $\mathbb{Z_2}[x] / \langle x^3-x \rangle$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z_3}[x] / \langle x^3-x \rangle$

So this is isomorphic with
$\mathbb{Z_2}[x] / \langle x \rangle$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z_2}[x] / \langle (x-1)^2 \rangle$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z_3}[x] / \langle x \rangle$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z_3}[x] / \langle x-1 \rangle$  $\times$ $\mathbb{Z_3}[x] / \langle x+1 \rangle$
by C.R.T.

If we follow this logic, then we would get $\mathbb{Z_2} \times  \mathbb{Z_2}[x] / \langle (x-1)^2 \rangle \times \mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_3}   $.

The problem is the first and second answers are not isomorphic because of the difference number of the units. This provide one thing is wrong answer. I've checked my book it said the second thing is right. Why are the first solution and answer incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first calculation fails because $x-1$ and $x+1$ are not coprime.

Assume to the contrary that $x+1$ and $x-1$ are coprime in $\mathbb Z_6[x]$, then there are $f,g\in\mathbb Z_6[X]$ such that $$1=(x+1)\cdot f+(x-1)\cdot g.$$ Plugging in $x=1$, this yields $$1=2\cdot f(1),$$ which implies that $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_6$, which is incorrect.